# Он ждал, чтобы вдохновение пришло само, без зова.

Tags: синтаксис

*Он ждал, чтобы вдохновение пришло само, **без зова**.*

Oпределила *без зова* как предложное сочетание, как обстоятельство образа действия. Верно?

Спасибо!

Comment: Это обстоятельство отсутствия зова к действию. :-)

Comment: а если честно? : )

Comment: В силу того, что выбор у Вас очень небольшой, Вы, по-моему, сделали наиболее подходящий.

Comment: спасибо, что даете не только ответы, но улыбку тоже!!! =)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вы правы. Вопрос же: "Как?" — значит, типичный образ действия.

Comment: Думайте и о пунктуации как действии необходимом.

Comment: Чур меня! Я вашего имени не называл.